# Want to gererate a link for a cell with parameters based on user input

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, hyperlink

How to generate a link based on parameters inputed by a user for a specific cell?

ex:

cell A1: user input is "123456"
cell A1 link: [www.abc.com/?id=123456](http://www.abc.com/?id=123456)

Comment: How are you getting user input?

Comment: By just typing the number in the cell. e.g. user types 123456, cell displays 123456 with a link to www.abc.com/?id=123456

Comment: @ArmandoNeto, you want to have the link where you inputted the string?

Comment: Yes, e.g. user types 123456, cell displays 123456 with a link to www.abc.com/?id=123456

Comment: That would be possible only in script. would script be an option to you? @ArmandoNeto

Comment: If you are inputting into a cell, it will replace that value. So formula technically doesn't work unless you input it somewhere. But in script, you can detect if someone edited the values in a cell (can be a specific range) so when that happens, you manipulate the edited cell. That's what I did in my answer below. Kindly check if it works on you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the closest thing I can think of. If it is just solely generated by a formula, you can't input a text in a cell and expect it to have a different formula. So you need to have the links generated on another cells and the input on another cells

#### Formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A<>"",hyperlink("www.abc.com/?id="&A2:A),))
```

#### Formula:

[image: formula]

But via script, that would be possible:

#### Script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // if input is in "Sheet1!A2:A" range, convert to link automatically
  if(e.range.getRow() > 1 && e.range.getColumn() == 1 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() == 'Sheet1' && e.value != null) {
    e.range.setValue('=hyperlink("www.abc.com/?id='+ e.value +'")');
  }
}
```

#### Script output:

[image: output]

Comment: Yep, the script solution is what I was looking for, thanks a lot mate. By the way, where I can learn more about these scripts?

Comment: Hi @ArmandoNeto, you could try and see these [basic tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/tutorials). After that, you just gotta learn from experience and read google's documentations.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=HYPERLINK("www.abc.com/?id="&A1, A1)
```

[image]

for arrayformula use:

```
=INDEX(IF(A1:A, HYPERLINK("www.abc.com/?id="&A1:A, A1:A), ))
```

[image]